# Convert a csv into category-subcategory using array

Tags: python, arrays, categories

[image: input table is here]

Above is the input table i have in csv
    I am trying to use array and while loops in python. I am new to this language. Loops should occur twice to give Category\sub-category\sub-category_1 order...I am trying to use split().Ouput should be like below

```
 import csv
    with open('D:\\test.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='',quotechar='|') 
        data = [] 
    for name in reader:
        data[name] = []
```

[image: output should be like this]

Comment: 10 is the main category and 100 is a sub category of it & 1001,1002,1003 are sub categories of 100

Comment: I answered before you edit the question, now I am confused with your output. Main category has 2 digits? Sub category 3 digits? Sub sub category 4 digits? is this right?

Comment: yes.. u are right,... promotional materials and discounted products are again sub category of new products....

Comment: so Promotional Materials should be 101 and Discounted Products 102?

Comment: ahh u can assume that to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you read the lines of your csv and access the data then you can manipulate the way you want later.

```
cats = {}

with open('my.csv', "r") as ins:
    # check each line of the fine
    for line in ins:
        # remove double quotes: replace('"', '')
        # remove break line : rstrip()
        a = str(line).replace('"', '').rstrip().split('|')
        if a[0] != 'CatNo':
            cats[int(a[0])] = a[1:];

for p in cats:
    print 'cat_id: %d, value: %s' % (p, cats[p])

# you can access the value by the int ID
print cats[1001]
```

the output:

```
cat_id: 100, value: ['Best Sellers', 'Best Sellers']
cat_id: 1001, value: ['New this Month', 'New Products\\New this Month']
cat_id: 10, value: ['New Products', 'New Products']
cat_id: 1003, value: ['Previous Months', 'New Products\\Previous Months']
cat_id: 110, value: ['Promotional Material', 'Promotional Material']
cat_id: 120, value: ['Discounted Products & Special Offers', 'Discounted Products & Special Offers']
cat_id: 1002, value: ['Last Month', 'New Products\\Last Month']
['New this Month', 'New Products\\New this Month']
```

Updated script for your question:

```
categories = {}

def get_parent_category(cat_id):
    if len(cat_id) <= 2:
        return '';
    else:
        return cat_id[:-1]

with open('my.csv', "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        # remove double quotes: replace('"', '')
        # remove break line : rstrip()
        a = str(line).replace('"', '').rstrip().split('|')

        cat_id = a[0]

        if cat_id != 'CatNo':
            categories[cat_id] = {
                'parent': get_parent_category(cat_id),
                'desc': a[1],
                'long_desc': a[2]
            };

print 'Categories relations:'

for p in categories:

    parent = categories[p]['parent']
    output = categories[p]['desc']

    while parent != '':
        output = categories[parent]['desc'] + ' \\ ' + output
        parent = categories[parent]['parent']

    print '\t', output
```

output:

```
Categories relations:
  New Products
  New Products \ Best Sellers
  New Products \ Discounted Products & Special Offers
  New Products \ Best Sellers \ Previous Months
  New Products \ Best Sellers \ Last Month
  New Products \ Best Sellers \ New this Month
```

Comment: thanks mauricio but i want the output like in the image above

Comment: thankyou so much mauricio... it worked... i appreciate ur support